# Windows 7 cannot connect to network shares, Exchange server, Webmail... anything requiring authentication

Tags: http, networking, tcp, unc

I have been handed this Asus Ultrabook that had Outlook 2010 that was not connecting to our Exchange server.  It used to when in a different office.
On our office network, it can't.   I have 36 other computers (Win7/XP, Office2k10/2k3) that have no problems at all.
The odd thing is that it cannot connect to our exchange server's webmail either.
It just keeps requesting a username and password over and over.
My laptop loads his email account fine in both Outlook and webmail.

I've just done a full factory restore of this Ultrabook and it is still not connecting to our exchange server.  Or any other server (eg. our file shares) for that matter.

It does connect to my laptop's file shares, but I don't have a username/password setup for them.

It seems to be any network activities that require authentication...

Any suggestions?

*update:   I have since done a full HDD reformat/install of Win7 from an OEM DVD.  After installing the wifi drivers (ONLY) there is still the problem.  Even if I load browsable directory that requires standard kerberos username and password on the internet via the server's IP, it just keeps prompting for a username and password.  I'm seriously baffled!*

Comment: I also tried connecting to the internet through tethering with my iPhone...   The same website with the directory browsing via Windows authentication has the login issue where it just keeps requesting the username and password.

I plugged in the USBtoFastEthernet dongle the ultrabook came with and connected to our network via ethernet only and issue still exists with that adapter too.

I'm at a loss...   I really don't know how this is possible.

Comment: After hours of searching and reformats, I found a solution.
 
http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2009/09/04/windows-7-cannot-connect-to-newtork-drive/
 
The update the author adds for Win 7 Home Premium is the fix for me...
 
I can't understand how this could have been a problem on a brand new install from an OEM install source. Go figure – Microsoft!
 
Lucky I took an image of the HDD prior to all my reformats and factory restores.